# datediff from today to end of financial year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to calculate the days between today `GETDATE()` and end of the current financial year `20190331`.

```
datediff(dd,Getdate(), '20190331') DaysFinYearEnd
```

What is the best line of code to replace the hard coded value `20190331` with dynamically calculated end of year?

Comment: What do you mean `what is the best line of code to replace '20190331'`

Comment: What are you asking exactly??  Note: You should format your date better, and you should also not use 'dd' and start using 'day'; the short forms should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is one method:

```
datediff(day,
         Getdate(),
         datefromparts( (case when month(getdate()) >= 4 then 1 else 0 end) + year(getdate()), 3, 31)
        ) DaysFinYearEnd
```

Comment: does not work sorry error I get is.. datefromparts function requires 3 argument(s)

Comment: @pete . . . I think that's just a typo on the parens in the function call.

Comment: this work brilliantly thank you x found the typo